# (php, ajax) How should a server notice something for client?

Tags: php, ajax, interaction

There are interactive sites (for example this :)) which can notice events without refreshing anything. For example, when I get an answer, a red circle will appear up there. I understand that it can be done with sending `ajax` requests, say one about every  5 second - but it then would kill servers. Then how should a server send to clients that something changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX Polling Frequency - To long poll or not to long poll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842063/ajax-polling-frequency-to-long-poll-or-not-to-long-poll)

Answer (score 2):

Solutions like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) implement different ways to keep the client connected, including:

- HTML5 Websockets (New, pretty good, but not supported by older browsers)
- Flash plugin (Requires flash plugin, no mobile support)
- Long polling (Killer for traditional webservices)

Answer (score 1):

You can open an XHR that stays alive until the server has a state change to send the response.

This is known as *long polling*.

Comment: but this is still a lot of requesting isnt it?

Comment: I mean, this is still a continuous sending/receiving, overloading the server